# Does React have scroll animations like jQuery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am trying to make some divs slide into view depending on a scroll feature and also scroll the page down to certain points on button clicks, and was wondering if React has some built in features for this? Or, should I just use jQuery to do it? I have a good idea of how to do it in jQuery, but am fairly new to react. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No there isn't anything pre-built into React for handling scrolling. [There are tons of packages that help with that though](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll), you might want to check those out first before using jQuery because it will probably be easier to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesnt.

But you can use native [scrollIntoView api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) with option `{ behavior: 'smooth' }` to get it done easily. Note that it doesnt works properly for old browsers, so check [this polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) to support IE9+ and others.

Comment: Thank you! I finally figured out how to get this implemented and it works great! I was having a problem because for some reason all the components I called into my render function on my index.js main parent component would not accept an id (it wasn't visible in the elements tab on the console). I added divs around all the components that I wanted to scroll to, and gave them ids and it worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing as such in react because react is not a UI library like jQuery. You can use some library for smooth scroll such as **antd** or **material UI** and you can even use jQuery for that.

Answer (score 2):

React is just a library to build reusable user interfaces. It is not a framework, so it will not provide you with built-in features such as animations, form validations, etc.

Essentially, it helps you with efficient rendering of the View. It is up to you to choose your own tools to make the rest of your application. You may find custom packages that may help you do what you are seeking.

I would not use jQuery with React, because React already handles the DOM for you. In fact, React encourages the use of vanilla JavaScript, since the language has been improving a lot, especially since ES6 came along. There are many new features in the web APIs that will make your life easier. Although some might not yet be fully supported by all browsers, you can use a polyfill to make it work.